# Authentication with Auth0, swiftUI, and Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, swiftui, auth0

I am trying to add authentication via Auth0 to my app that uses Django Rest Framework for the API backend and swiftUI for the front end. I have successfully connected auth0 to both the backend and frontent (to DRF via [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/django/01-authorization) tutorial and to swift via [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native) tutorial). However, I am struggling to connect the two. I want to figure out a way to use Auth0's universal login page yet still have the user data show up in my Django Rest Framework API. Do you know of a way to do this, or is there a better way to implement this type of user authentication in my app?

Here is the swift code I have been using to create the Universal Login Page. I am wondering if maybe I have to add an API call to DRF once the Auth0 verifies the credentials, but I am not sure.

```
Button("Login") {
                Auth0
                    .webAuth()
                    .audience("https://waittimes/api") // the api in auth0
                    .start { result in
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let credentials):
                            print("Obtained credentials: \(credentials)")
                            // maybe use access token to send a request to my DRF API??
                        case .failure(let error):
                            print("Failed with: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not a direct answer to your question but token authentication with django drf and an ios app works perfectly.
After login through youre app you will get a token for the logged user in your app. You put this token in every api request to django.

[drf token auth](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)